# Iterate over 2d array in an expanding circular spiral

Tags: python, matrix, loops, geometry, spiral

Given an `n` by `n` matrix `M`, at row `i` and column `j`, I'd like to iterate over all the neighboring values in a circular spiral.

The point of doing this is to test some function, `f`, which depends on M, to find the radius away from `(i, j)` in which `f` returns `True`. So, `f` looks like this:

```
def f(x, y):
    """do stuff with x and y, and return a bool"""
```

and would be called like this:

```
R = numpy.zeros(M.shape, dtype=numpy.int)
# for (i, j) in M
for (radius, (cx, cy)) in circle_around(i, j):
    if not f(M[i][j], M[cx][cy]):
       R[cx][cy] = radius - 1
       break
```

Where `circle_around` is the function that returns (an iterator to) indices in a circular spiral. So for every point in `M`, this code would compute and store the radius from that point in which `f` returns `True`.

If there's a more efficient way of computing `R`, I'd be open to that, too.

---

## **Update:**

Thanks to everyone who submitted answers. I've written a short function to plot the output from your `circle_around` iterators, to show what they do. If you update your answer or post a new one, you can use this code to validate your solution.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def plot(g, name):
    plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray')
    ax.xaxis.grid(color='gray')

    X, Y = [], []
    for i in xrange(100):
        (r, (x, y)) = g.next()
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
        print "%d: radius %d" % (i, r)

    plt.plot(X, Y, 'r-', linewidth=2.0)
    plt.title(name)
    plt.savefig(name + ".png")
```

Here are the results:
`plot(circle_around(0, 0), "F.J")`:
[image: circle_around by F.J]

`plot(circle_around(0, 0, 10), "WolframH")`:
[image: circle_around by WolframH]

I've coded up Magnesium's suggestion as follows:

```
def circle_around_magnesium(x, y):
    import math
    theta = 0
    dtheta = math.pi / 32.0
    a, b = (0, 1) # are there better params to use here?
    spiral = lambda theta : a + b*theta
    lastX, lastY = (x, y)
    while True:
        r = spiral(theta)
        X = r * math.cos(theta)
        Y = r * math.sin(theta)
        if round(X) != lastX or round(Y) != lastY:
            lastX, lastY = round(X), round(Y)
            yield (r, (lastX, lastY))
        theta += dtheta
```

`plot(circle_around(0, 0, 10), "magnesium")`:
[image: circle_around by Magnesium]

As you can see, none of the results that satisfy the interface I'm looking for have produced a circular spiral that covers all of the indices around 0, 0. F.J's is the closest, although WolframH's hits the right points, just not in spiral order.

Comment: Can you confirm that your arrays are very large or you have to do this many times or the truth function is expensive or...? I could come up with something, but it seems like premature optimization unless you really need to avoid testing outside the radius. Of course the simple solution would be to find the radius for every false point in the array and then just find the smallest radius. Neat problem though if you really need it.

Comment: @yakiimo, the arrays have 1-2 million entries.

Comment: Does F.J's answer work for you or do you need a real circle?

Comment: I would prefer a real circle.

Comment: FYI I still have this on my to-do list but it's quite long at the moment.

Comment: @yakiimo -- awesome. I've been meaning to write some code to visualize the generated indices to show their spiral-ness (or lack thereof), but I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: [similar (basically same) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330181/algorithm-for-finding-nearest-object-on-2d-grid) but still not calculating based on a circular radius

Comment: I believe the code I posted will give you the answer you want although in a slightly different way than you asked for. If using a square iterator, it's really important to handle the case of the first point not necessarily being the closest due to the square shape of the iterator.

Comment: Is the ordering of the points important in the spiral, or do you simply want all points `(i,j)` such that `f(i,j) < r`?

Comment: @Hooked, I want them ordered by ascending radius. Within any set of points at the same distance, I suppose I don't care what order they are returned in, although it would be nice if it was a nice order.

Comment: @JasonSundram: Why does your matrix have negative indices?

Comment: Related math.stackexchange question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740130/how-to-enumerate-2d-integer-coordinates-ordered-by-euclidean-distance

Answer (score 13):

Since it was mentioned that the order of the points do not matter, I've simply ordered them by the angle (`arctan2`) in which they appear at a given radius. Change `N` to get more points.

```
from numpy import *
N = 8

# Find the unique distances
X,Y = meshgrid(arange(N),arange(N))
G = sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
U = unique(G)

# Identify these coordinates
blocks = [[pair for pair in zip(*where(G==idx))] for idx in U if idx<N/2]

# Permute along the different orthogonal directions
directions = array([[1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[-1,-1]])

all_R = []
for b in blocks:
    R = set()
    for item in b:
        for x in item*directions:
            R.add(tuple(x))

    R = array(list(R))

    # Sort by angle
    T = array([arctan2(*x) for x in R])
    R = R[argsort(T)]
    all_R.append(R)

# Display the output
from pylab import *
colors = ['r','k','b','y','g']*10
for c,R in zip(colors,all_R):
    X,Y = map(list,zip(*R))

    # Connect last point
    X = X + [X[0],]
    Y = Y + [Y[0],]
    scatter(X,Y,c=c,s=150)
    plot(X,Y,color=c)

axis('equal')
show()
```

Gives for `N=8`:

[image]

More points `N=16` (sorry for the colorblind):

[image]

This clearly approaches a circle and hits every grid point in order of increasing radius.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

One way for yielding points with increasing distance is to **break it down** into *easy parts*, and then **merge** the results of the parts together. It's rather obvious that `itertools.merge` should do the merging. The *easy parts* are **columns**, because for fixed x the points (x, y) can be ordered by looking at the value of y only.

Below is a (simplistic) implementation of that algorithm. Note that the *squared* Euclidian distance is used, and that the center point is included. Most importantly, only points (x, y) with x in `range(x_end)` are considered, but I think that's OK for your use case (where `x_end` would be `n` in your notation above).

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import count

def distance_column(x0, x, y0):
    dist_x = (x - x0) ** 2
    yield dist_x, (x, y0)
    for dy in count(1):
        dist = dist_x + dy ** 2
        yield dist, (x, y0 + dy)
        yield dist, (x, y0 - dy)

def circle_around(x0, y0, end_x):
    for dist_point in merge(*(distance_column(x0, x, y0) for x in range(end_x))):
        yield dist_point
```

**Edit:** Test code:

```
def show(circle):
    d = dict((p, i) for i, (dist, p) in enumerate(circle))
    max_x = max(p[0] for p in d) + 1
    max_y = max(p[1] for p in d) + 1
    return "\n".join(" ".join("%3d" % d[x, y] if (x, y) in d else "   " for x in range(max_x + 1)) for y in range(max_y + 1))

import itertools
print(show(itertools.islice(circle_around(5, 5, 11), 101)))
```

Result of test (points are numbered in the order they are yielded by `circle_around`):

```
             92  84  75  86  94                
     98  73  64  52  47  54  66  77 100        
     71  58  40  32  27  34  42  60  79        
 90  62  38  22  16  11  18  24  44  68  96    
 82  50  30  14   6   3   8  20  36  56  88    
 69  45  25   9   1   0   4  12  28  48  80    
 81  49  29  13   5   2   7  19  35  55  87    
 89  61  37  21  15  10  17  23  43  67  95    
     70  57  39  31  26  33  41  59  78        
     97  72  63  51  46  53  65  76  99        
             91  83  74  85  93
```

**Edit 2:** If you really do need negative values of `i`, replace `range(end_x)` with `range(-end_x, end_x)` in the `cirlce_around` function.

Comment: this doesn't look anything like a spiral -- see my updates to the question. did I miss something? What got produced was this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h0mNa.png

Comment: @JasonSundram: 1) I assumed nonnegative indices, because you wrote about an n x n-Matrix.  2) I also assumed that the order of points of the same distance is not important. That's the impression I got from your question and comments. Is that wrong?

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for the clarification and the code to show how your answer works. I've also regenerated the image for your code in the post to more accurately depict how it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the x and y helical indices you notice that both of them can be defined in a recursive manner. Therefore, it is quite easy to come up with a function that recursively generates the correct indices:

```
def helicalIndices(n):
    num = 0
    curr_x, dir_x, lim_x, curr_num_lim_x = 0, 1, 1, 2
    curr_y, dir_y, lim_y, curr_num_lim_y = -1, 1, 1, 3
    curr_rep_at_lim_x, up_x = 0, 1
    curr_rep_at_lim_y, up_y = 0, 1

    while num < n:
        if curr_x != lim_x:
            curr_x +=  dir_x
        else:
            curr_rep_at_lim_x += 1
            if curr_rep_at_lim_x == curr_num_lim_x - 1:
                if lim_x < 0:
                    lim_x = (-lim_x) + 1
                else:
                    lim_x = -lim_x
                curr_rep_at_lim_x = 0
                curr_num_lim_x += 1
                dir_x = -dir_x
        if curr_y != lim_y:
            curr_y = curr_y + dir_y
        else:
            curr_rep_at_lim_y += 1
            if curr_rep_at_lim_y == curr_num_lim_y - 1:
                if lim_y < 0:
                    lim_y = (-lim_y) + 1
                else:
                    lim_y = -lim_y
                curr_rep_at_lim_y = 0
                curr_num_lim_y += 1
                dir_y = -dir_y
        r = math.sqrt(curr_x*curr_x + curr_y*curr_y)        
        yield (r, (curr_x, curr_y))
        num += 1

    hi = helicalIndices(101)
    plot(hi, "helicalIndices")
```

[image: helicalIndices]

As you can see from the image above, this gives exactly what's asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a loop based implementation for `circle_around()`:

```
def circle_around(x, y):
    r = 1
    i, j = x-1, y-1
    while True:
        while i < x+r:
            i += 1
            yield r, (i, j)
        while j < y+r:
            j += 1
            yield r, (i, j)
        while i > x-r:
            i -= 1
            yield r, (i, j)
        while j > y-r:
            j -= 1
            yield r, (i, j)
        r += 1
        j -= 1
        yield r, (i, j)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a square snake around i,j correct? Just a warning to Jason in case he actually needs a real radius.

Comment: upvoted since it's the closest to what I've asked for, but it is a square, not a circular spiral.

Comment: @JasonSundram - Nice edit, definitely clarifies what you're looking for.  It would be really helpful if you could manually generate the points you would want up to a few loops around the circle and add that to your question as well, that would make it a lot easier to try to code a solution that matches your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm pretty embarrassed this is the best I have come up with so far. But maybe it will help you. Since it's not actually a circular iterator, I had to accept your test function as an argument.

Problems:

- not optimized to skip points outside the array
- still uses a square iterator, but it does find the closest point
- i haven't used numpy, so it's made for list of lists. the two points you need to change are commented
- i left the square iterator in a long form so it's easier to read. it could be more DRY

Here is the code. The key solution to your question is the top level "spiral_search" function which adds some extra logic on top of the square spiral iterator to make sure that the closest point is found.

```
from math import sqrt

#constants
X = 0
Y = 1

def spiral_search(array, focus, test):
    """
    Search for the closest point to focus that satisfies test.
    test interface: test(point, focus, array)
    points structure: [x,y] (list, not tuple)
    returns tuple of best point [x,y] and the euclidean distance from focus
    """
    #stop if focus not in array
    if not _point_is_in_array(focus, array): raise IndexError("Focus must be within the array.")
    #starting closest radius and best point
    stop_radius = None
    best_point = None 
    for point in _square_spiral(array, focus):
        #cheap stop condition: when current point is outside the stop radius
        #(don't calculate outside axis where more expensive)
        if (stop_radius) and (point[Y] == 0) and (abs(point[X] - focus[X]) >= stop_radius):
            break #current best point is already as good or better so done
        #otherwise continue testing for closer solutions
        if test(point, focus, array):
            distance = _distance(focus, point)
            if (stop_radius == None) or (distance < stop_radius):
                stop_radius = distance
                best_point = point
    return best_point, stop_radius

def _square_spiral(array, focus):
    yield focus
    size = len(array) * len(array[0]) #doesn't work for numpy
    count = 1
    r_square = 0
    offset = [0,0]
    rotation = 'clockwise'
    while count < size:
        r_square += 1
        #left
        dimension = X
        direction = -1
        for point in _travel_dimension(array, focus, offset, dimension, direction, r_square):
            yield point
            count += 1
        #up
        dimension = Y
        direction = 1
        for point in _travel_dimension(array, focus, offset, dimension, direction, r_square):
            yield point
            count += 1
        #right
        dimension = X
        direction = 1
        for point in _travel_dimension(array, focus, offset, dimension, direction, r_square):
            yield point
            count += 1
        #down
        dimension = Y
        direction = -1
        for point in _travel_dimension(array, focus, offset, dimension, direction, r_square):
            yield point
            count += 1

def _travel_dimension(array, focus, offset, dimension, direction, r_square):
    for value in range(offset[dimension] + direction, direction*(1+r_square), direction):
        offset[dimension] = value
        point = _offset_to_point(offset, focus)
        if _point_is_in_array(point, array):
            yield point

def _distance(focus, point):
    x2 = (point[X] - focus[X])**2
    y2 = (point[Y] - focus[Y])**2
    return sqrt(x2 + y2)

def _offset_to_point(offset, focus):
    return [offset[X] + focus[X], offset[Y] + focus[Y]]

def _point_is_in_array(point, array):
    if (0 <= point[X] < len(array)) and (0 <= point[Y] < len(array[0])): #doesn't work for numpy
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I'm trying to go through and visualize the indices people are returning for `circle_around` -- is there any way you can convert this solution to just return those spiral indices?

Comment: The reason I wasn't totally satisfied is that this doesn't return a spiral iteration as you asked for. It uses a square iteration but is smart enough to know when the actual closest point has been found (rather than just the first which may not be the closest). So it will work for you to find the first point if you pass it your test function. I did pseudocode for several other ways but they were all expensive in terms of calculating ***unique*** points that are along an actual circle or spiral. Will passing in your test function not work well enough?

Comment: I just wanted to be able to visualize your results to compare them to everyone else's answers. I guess I'll have to come up with another way to do that.

Comment: if you have your own way to visualize, all you need is to iterate through _square_spiral().

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, I'd start like this:

```
def xxx():
    for row in M[i-R:i+R+1]:
        for val in row[j-R:j+r+1]:
            yield val
```

I'm not sure how much order you want for your spiral, is it important at all? does it have to be in increasing R order? or perhaps clockwise starting at particular azimuth?

What is the distance measure for R, manhattan? euclidean? something else?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the equation for an Archimedean spiral:

```
r(theta) = a + b*theta
```

and then convert the polar coordinates (r,theta) into (x,y), by using

```
x = r*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(theta)
```

`cos` and `sin` are in the `math` library. Then round the resulting x and y to integers. You can offset x and y afterward by the starting index, to get the final indices of the array.

However, if you are just interested in finding the first radius where f returns true, I think it would be more beneficial to do the following pseudocode:

```
for (i,j) in matrix:
    radius = sqrt( (i-i0)^2 + (j-j0)^2) // (i0,j0) is the "center" of your spiral
    radiuslist.append([radius, (i,j)])
sort(radiuslist) // sort by the first entry in each element, which is the radius
// This will give you a list of each element of the array, sorted by the
// "distance" from it to (i0,j0)
for (rad,indices) in enumerate(radiuslist):
    if f(matrix[indices]):
        // you found the first one, do whatever you want
```

Comment: this does return a circular spiral, but it doesn't pass through all the grid points around the starting point. I've updated the question with a picture of what this produces.