# Check nearby point in 2d array with boundary conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a program that checks a coordinate in an array of arrays, and searches nearby coordinates to find the nearest 5 with an 'event'. However, when at the edges of the grid, in this example (0,0), I face the problem of the same event being returned multiple times but with a different 'distance' away (this distance is the Manhattan distance).

I think this occurs because I have parameters set the that if the coordinate it wants to check is outside of the grid (less than 0) it's value is changed to match the boundary (0).

```
let check = (x, y, d) => {
        if (x > 20) {
            x = 20;
        }
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (y > 20) {
            y = 20;
        }
        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        }

        if (Main[x][y].event) {
            let info = {
                x: x - (xRange/2),
                y: y - (xRange/2),
                event: Main[x][y].event,
                distance: d,
                ticket: Main[x][y].tickets[0],
            }
            return info;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

let findEvents = (x, y) => {
        let nearby = [];
        let info;

        // Check point x, y
        if (Main[x][y].event) {
            info = {
                    x: x - (xRange/2),
                    y: y - (xRange/2),
                    event: Main[x][y].event,
                    distance: 0,
                    tickets: Main[x][y].tickets,
            }
            nearby.push(info);
        }

        for (let d = 1; d <= 40; d++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < d + 1; i++) {

                info = check(x - d + i, y - i, d);

                if (info) {
                    nearby.push(info);
                }
                if ((nearby.length > 5) &&
                    (nearby[(nearby.length-1)].distance !=
                        nearby[(nearby.length-2)].distance)) {
                    return nearby.slice(0,-1);
                }

                info = check(x + d - i, y + i, d);

                if (info) {
                    nearby.push(info);
                }
                if ((nearby.length > 5) &&
                    (nearby[(nearby.length-1)].distance !=
                        nearby[(nearby.length-2)].distance)) {
                    return nearby.slice(0,-1);
                }
            }

            for (let i = 1; i < d; i++) {

                info = check(x - i, y + d - i, d);

                if (info) {
                    nearby.push(info);
                }
                if ((nearby.length > 5) &&
                    (nearby[(nearby.length-1)].distance !=
                        nearby[(nearby.length-2)].distance)) {
                        return nearby.slice(0,-1);
                }

                info = check(x + d - i, y - i, d);

                if (info) {
                    nearby.push(info);
                }
                if ((nearby.length > 5) &&
                    (nearby[(nearby.length-1)].distance !=
                        nearby[(nearby.length-2)].distance)) {
                        return nearby.slice(0,-1);
                }
            }
        }
        return nearby;
    }
```

Any tips on how to avoid this? (or to clean up my code in general :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your find_events method yet, but it seems like to avoid the problem you described, you should return false from `check` whenever the point is outside the grid. Thus:

```
let check = (x, y, d) => {
  if (x > 20 || x < 0 || y > 20 ||y < 0) {
    return false;
  }
...
```

Comment: yep that works :D I got a bit too concentrated on the values that were out of range and seemed to ignore that it would still try other values at the same distance.
I based my method on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330181/algorithm-for-finding-nearest-object-on-2d-grid if you want to try and understand better :) Thanks